# Gothic Medieval font that you can embed With Cufón?

Tags: fonts, cufon

I'm looking for a font in Gothic Medieval style that I can embed with [Cufón](http://wiki.github.com/sorccu/cufon/about). I tried with the [Cloister Black](http://www.dafont.com/Cloister-Black.Font) .ttf file but the [generator](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate) responded with:

> The file you uploaded could not be
>   converted. Currently only TrueType
>   (TTF), OpenType (OTF), Printer Font
>   Binary (PFB) and PostScript fonts are
>   supported.
>
> If you're sure the font is valid, it
>   is likely that the author of the font
>   has decided to not allow modification
>   and/or embedding of the font. This can
>   happen quite often especially with
>   "freeware" TrueType fonts. You must
>   contact the author of the font for a
>   less restricted version.

Comment: For those voting 'close' becasue off-topic, can you suggest a SO-like site with typographists where this question is on-topic

Comment: Maybe just change the title of the question so it sounds like you're trying to solve a problem with Cufon rather than asking for a font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all free Blackletter fonts, and the site's "@font-face Kit Generator" supports Cufon utility as well:

[Font Squirrel Blackletter Fonts](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/style/Blackletter)

[@font-face kit generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)

Answer (score 1):

Working for 12 years in the printing industry, I ran into problems with customer fonts that wouldn't embed in PDF documents, which was required for our workflow. As it turns out, a lot of fonts are "freeware" and simply have badly formed portions, missing glyphs, etc. Also, font authors can sometimes mistakenly leave the tags enabled that prohibit embedding or printing, etc.

The best course of action would be to contact the publisher or author of the font to see anything can be done. (Perhaps embedding was not meant to be denied.)

There are tools like [ttfpatch](http://www.derwok.de/downloads/ttfpatch/) that can *change* the tags inside TTF fonts, but like many things, you could be violating a copyright if you use it incorrectly.